# How do I clear EditText after all fragments above it have been popped?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

In an Android project, I have 3 fragments, and I navigate through them during an operation the user does.

> FragmentA -> FragmentB -> FragmentC

When the user finishes the operation, I do a `popBackStack` to return to FragmentA

```
if(getFragmentManager()!=null)
    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(getFragmentManager()
                    .getBackStackEntryAt(0)
                    .getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
```

### My question is:

I have an `EditText`, where the user writes some text, and after the call to `popBackStack()`, the fragment shows with the text still there.

Is there a way to know that the fragment has been popped and reset that `EditText`?

### EDIT

This is what I use to go to next screen:

```
try {
    String backStateName = ((Object) fragment).getClass().getName();
    String fragmentTag = backStateName;

    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentTag);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
    if (addToBackStack)
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
    ft.commit();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Logging.logException(e);
}
```

Comment: for that you can code in your onResume of the FragmentA just do this in your onResume edittext.setText("");

Comment: when i popbackstack, it doesnt seem to pass by the onResume method on FragmentA

Comment: have you added your fragments in fragmentTransactions or replaced the Fragments?

Comment: @Ric Simply set youreditText.setText(""); when you move from one fragment to another fragment. You know when you move from one fragment to another so simply just code their it will very easy for you.

Comment: but when i go back from FragmentB to A, the EditTextBox would be reseted, and i just want to reset it ,when i finish the process and call that popbackstack

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using flags.

The idea is that when the `popBackStack()` is called, the Activity sets a flag which will be checked by FragmentA in its `onResume()`.

Simplified steps:

1. When popping off FragmentC, do this:

   ```
   clearEditTextOfA = true;
   ```
2. in `onResume()` of FragmentA, do this:

   ```
   if (activityCallback.shouldClearEditText()) {
       editText.setText("");
   }
   ```

   The `activityCallback` is an interface which lets a Fragment communicate with the Activity it is placed in. See [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface).
3. Instead of doing `ft.add()`, do `ft.replace()`.

   This will make the `onResume()` of your Fragments get called whenever they change.

Comment: i tried it , but for some reason, onResume() ins't called

Comment: I've updated the answer. You should be using `fragmentTransaction.replace()` instead of `fragmentTransaction.add()`. Then your issue will be fixed.