# Changing value from EditText on a Fragment in BackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im trying to change the Text from a EditText in a Fragment that is present in the BackStack.

I navigate through 4 Fragments, and when im in the last, i want to call a method present in the first fragment of the backstack to write something in a EditTextBox in that same fragment

i have a button in the last fragment that when i press i do this:

```
    ((FragmentABC) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("package.FragmentABC")).resetPurchaseValue();
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(0).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

and the in FragmentABC i have a method like so:

```
public void resetPurchaseValue(){
    if(etValue!=null)
        etValue.setText("0.00");
}
```

Using breakpoints i can see that this method is called, but when the fragment appears in screen the EditText doesn't have the value "0.00", but the original value written before the navigation through the fragments.

Comment: I posted answer to your initial problem, which is only minutely different from this one. Did it work for that situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clear EditText after all fragments above it have been popped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192417/how-do-i-clear-edittext-after-all-fragments-above-it-have-been-popped)